# Ag-grid external filter does not work properly with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I was trying to use an Ag-grid external filter with React as given the documentation. I was playing with the demo. Then realized that the filter works only for 1st time. For 2nd time onwards it does not filter out the values.
[Link to ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/#example-external-filter)

```html
externalFilterChanged = newValue => {
    ageType = newValue;
    this.gridApi.onFilterChanged();
  };

  isExternalFilterPresent = () => {
    return ageType != 'everyone';
  };

  doesExternalFilterPass = node => {
    switch (ageType) {
      case 'below25':
        return node.data.age < 25;
      case 'between25and50':
        return node.data.age >= 25 && node.data.age <= 50;
      case 'above50':
        return node.data.age > 50;
      case 'dateAfter2008':
        return asDate(node.data.date) > new Date(2008, 1, 1);
      default:
        return true;
    }
  };
```

[Link to Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/hrAOajZeBVOlELSd)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Its hard to help without any code

Comment: The react example from the docs doesn't work. But it works if I copy to my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-wescoff-7xn9i?file=/src/index.tsx:2418-2440)

Comment: @NearHuscarl I also tried and found out that it is because of the react version. It works when we use the latest version of the react. Thanks for your help.